# Add div jquery in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

so when I selected some of the div like this

```
  var filter = $('.album1.phonepic');
```

I want to add them in to an empty I div already have, but only 4 for each one.

```
   <div class="emptydiv1"></div>
   <div class="emptydiv2"></div>
   var count = 0;

   for(var i = 0; i <= filter.length; i++){
      if(count <= 4){
          $('.emptydiv1').append(filter[i]);
          count++;
      }else {
          $('.emptydiv2').append(filter[i]);
      }        
   }
```

whenever I try to loop the selected variables its not working. Please help me

Comment: You need to be more clear what the problem is, what is not working and what are you expecting? Also you are missing a `.` in your class selector (`$('emptydiv2')`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here some simple code that will work for you**

```js
var filter = $('.album1.phonepic');

for (var i = 0; i <= filter.length; i++) {
    var emptyDiv = i < 4?$('.emptydiv1'):$('.emptydiv2');
    emptyDiv.append(filter[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 1</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 2</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 3</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 4</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 5</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 6</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 7</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 8</span>

<hr/>
<div class="emptydiv1">div 1</div>
<hr/>
<div class="emptydiv2">div 2</div>
```

**or another way using `:lt()` and `:gt:()`**

```js
var albums  = $('.album1.phonepic');
   

$('.emptydiv1').append(albums.filter(':lt(4)'))
$('.emptydiv2').append(albums.filter(':gt(3)'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 1</span>
    <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 2</span>
    <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 3</span>
    <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 4</span>
    <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 5</span>
    <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 6</span>
    <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 7</span>
    <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 8</span>

<hr/>
    <div class="emptydiv1">div 1</div>
<hr/>
    <div class="emptydiv2">div 2</div>
```

**or array slice way**

```js
var _array = $('.album1.phonepic');

$('.emptydiv2').append(_array.slice(4))
$('.emptydiv1').append(_array.slice(0,4))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 1</span>
        <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 2</span>
        <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 3</span>
        <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 4</span>
        <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 5</span>
        <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 6</span>
        <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 7</span>
        <span class="album1 phonepic">Test 8</span>

    <hr/>
        <div class="emptydiv1">div 1</div>
    <hr/>
        <div class="emptydiv2">div 2</div>
```

Comment: @pexichdu glad if u helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
 var filter = $('.album1.phonepic');

   for(var i = 0; i <= filter.length; i++){
      if(i < 4){ // set condition to only < instead of <=
          $('.emptydiv1').append(filter[i]);
          
      }else {
          $('.emptydiv2').append(filter[i]); // add . here before class name
      }        
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emptydiv1"></div>
 <hr/>
<div class="emptydiv2"></div>

<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 1</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 2</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 3</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 4</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 5</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 6</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 7</span>
<span class="album1 phonepic">Test 8</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

[Slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) it

```
$('.emptydiv2').append($('.album1.phonepic').slice(3))
$('.emptydiv1').append($('.album1.phonepic').slice(0,3))
```

Comment: Thanks @СеменихинМаксим
There was a race condition in previous suggestion. now it' ok.

Comment: Oh, you mean less then 4 exclusive, OK. I still think my solution is better then loop with conditions.

Comment: 1)you did twice search through all dom model for `.album1.phonepic`
2) you answer text is still to does not match the code you provided. But your solution is good